# How to use Apache ActiveMQ Artemis in Kubernetes networking

Tags: networking, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have setup a cluster within kubernetes using jgroups and the cluster appears to form correctly, each node has a local ip and a public ip, when I connect to one of the nodes using the public ip all is fine but the list of available nodes that is returned to the client (wildfly instance) contains the local ips of the nodes rather than their public ones, I have defined the connector with the public ip

```
<connectors>
     <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://{public ip}:61616</connector>
    </connectors>
```

and then configured the broadcast as

```
<broadcast-groups>
 <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
  <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
  <jgroups-file>jgroups-file_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
  <jgroups-channel>activemq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
  <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
</broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>
```

and then configured the discvery as

```
<discovery-groups>
 <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
  <jgroups-file>jgroups-file_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
  <jgroups-channel>activemq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
  <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
</discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
```

and finally the cluster as

```
<cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
```

Whenever I force a node to shutdown the client reconnects but fails and reports the local ip of the node, I was under the impression that the connector defined in the broker was used to broadcast to other members of the cluster but it uses the local ip is that correct?

Wildfly runs and send and receives messages but every few minutes I get the following log

```
14:27:31,463 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.recovery] (Periodic Recovery) AMQ122015: Can not connect to XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration=[TransportConfiguration(name=, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?trustStorePassword=****&port=61616&sslEnabled=true&host=x-x-x-x&trustStorePath=client-ts], discoveryConfiguration=null, username=username, password=****, JNDI_NAME=java:/RemoteJmsXA] on auto-generated resource recovery: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.recovery.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.connect(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.java:311)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.recovery.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.java:239)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.recovery.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.recover(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.java:69)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapperImpl.recover(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapperImpl.java:106)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecoveryFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:634)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:226)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:171)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:770)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:382)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior as you are connecting through a load balancer. You can work around that by setting `useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false` and specifying servers explicitly in your connection URL.

When using WildFly, the connection factory or pooled connection factory must be configured with the attribute `use-topology-for-load-balancing` set to false. This is how to set this from the CLI (replace remote-artemis with your actual name):

```sh
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/pooled-connection-factory=remote-artemis:write-attribute(name=use-topology-for-load-balancing, value=false)
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply, useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false in the acceptor?

Comment: Nope, it's a client's connection URL parameter.

Comment: The client is a wildfly instance, setup following master the boss guide, not sure how i would specify those params

Comment: Thank You once again, I think my version of wildfly (16.0.0 final) doesn't support the attribute

Answer (score 0):

Got it working eventually by creating a service per pod and putting public ip in the connector definition for each node